# Git saying there are changes to my .gitignore but "git status" shows "nothing to commit"

Tags: git, branch, gitignore

Currently working on a branch off master, and added something to .gitignore. I committed all my changes and tried checking out another branch but I get:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
  .gitignore
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

When i run `git status`, I get:

```
On branch feature/blahblah
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Does this mean git is not tracking my .gitignore file? If so, how do I get it to recognize the file?

Comment: have you `git add .`?

Comment: yeah but i still get "nothing to commit"

Comment: Have you tried doing a `git stash` and then doing whatever you were going to do? It wouldn't help you figure out what is going on, but it might work.

Comment: Does `git clean -dxn` show the `.gitignore` file?. This will show all the files `git clean` _would_ remove (i.e. it won't remove anything). If it shows `.gitignore` it means the file is either untracked or ignored.

Comment: This is a puzzler; I have tried to reproduce this scenario without success, but my gut tells me it has something to do with filters, line endings, and the like. What hash values do you get when you run `git hash-object .gitignore`, `git hash-object .gitignore --no-filters`, and `git ls-files -s .gitignore`? Also, what does `git config core.autocrlf` return? Finally, what is in your `.gitattributes` file?

Comment: i tried git clean as well. @DavidDeutsch - I solved the issue, take a look at my answer below. Simple yet such a headache...ugh. Wasted time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if this happens to anyone, somehow, someway, run:

```
git rm --cached .gitignore
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you, by chance, add a `.gitignore` line to your `.gitignore` file, so that it's ignoring itself? If so, remove it; it's best *not* to ignore the `.gitignore` file. Other places besides `.gitignore` that might be responsible are your global `core.excludesfile` setting, or a `.git/info/excludes` file in your repository (which would not get checked in). Neither of these are good practice in general, but some specific cases might require them (e.g., one developer uses a different editor than the other people on the project so he needs a different set of ignored files), so the options are available. See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/ for more details.

That seems most likely to be your problem.

Comment: i did not add .gitignore to my .gitignore

Comment: What does your .gitignore contain? Maybe there's a wildcard that's matching more than you intend.

Comment: i checked and it definitely doesn't have a pattern ignore .gitignore

Comment: If the file were ignored, `git checkout` would just overwrite it without warning.